# Would a polarizing filter help get better images from a security camera pointed out a window?

Tags: filters, polarizer, glass, security

I'm evaluating some security cameras for home use.

To avoid vandalism, I'm probably going to have to position the cameras inside the house, facing out the windows into a not very intense southern exposure. I need *very* good images from these cameras.

Do you think that polarizing filters would help cut reflections and glare in this case? I doubt that I could buy filters to fit the cameras but I could probably rig something seeing that I will probably stealth the cameras anyway.

I would have to deal with the light loss from the filter, of course.

Comment: I have a Foscam FI8908W that I could point out a window and give you an example. Are you by chance looking at that model?

Comment: Check with your local laws regarding stealth cameras!

Comment: if you would use something like Hoya HD, then the light loss would be very small. I also have one Hoya PRO1 and the difference seems to be very big.

Comment: dpollitt, a screenshot from the Foscam would be very helpful.

Comment: good point unapiedra

Answer (score 3):

The one point to be wary of: any additional layer of glass can add flare or reflections.

What I would think would be better would be something along the lines of a long lens hood that fits flush with the glass, so that any light coming not from the scene itself does not reach the lens, reducing stray light and improving the quality of the recording. Also, if your "Lens hood" fits flush with the window, you will not have an issue with glare or reflection from it.

Some reasonably thick black cardboard should do the trick.

If you are using double glazing, a polarizer might still be required because you can only align your lens hood with the internal glass layer, and you'd want it at the "back" right in from of the camera lens.

Comment: Just what I was going to say :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have reflections, a polariser should help quite a bit in all cases that I can think of.

Comment: Good point - it possibly would change during the day. I'd get one and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a polaroid filter , this would help to reduce the reflections.

An example : Without - With polaroid filter[image: example]
source :  http://www.paddling.net/sameboat/archives/sameboat496.html

As you can see you will have a better view from whats under the water (or the reflecting surface) but it also have his disadvantages.

On the otherside you can also try a little trick:
Place your camera (or lens) to your window , make sure the lens hit the surface.
The window will work as a kind of filter that you normally put on your lens, so you wont see the reflection of your lens in the glass.

*Note:*

*I m not sure that it works on all windows and I think that it works when you make an angle (cam-window) of 90 degrees.*